# What are some of the best Software Testing Courses for a beginner?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-design

I am a complete novice in software testing. I want to learn more about black-box/functional testing in general. Which courses(free or paid Text/video courses) could i use to learn better to write test cases, create test scenarios, learn writing clear defects , negative testing...etc.

Comment: ISTQB is the best one to get certified

Comment: I'm voting to close as this is really a matter of opinion, particularly when talking about such controversial certifications like ISTQB.

Comment: This or similar question was asked many times. Asking it again shows no effort from OP.

Comment: One way to make this question more askable and answerable would be for OP to do some research about courses available/considered, and ask about them. But in current form, closing is the right thing to do, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Although I have voted this to be closed, because this is a primarily opinion based question- best is a subjective term which is dependent on a person's perspective of best.

Instead of Testing courses, I can give you a good list of reading materials though- because this website is a store house of these kinda things.

[Blogs to follow to further learning](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/336/blogs-to-follow-to-further-learning)

[How can I transition into getting into QA?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3846/how-can-i-transition-into-getting-into-qa)

[How to become a good QA employee](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7621/how-to-become-a-good-qa-employee)

[Suggested books to start on software testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing)

Another point : Before you post, please research a bit, because this question has been asked N times, with the same answer.